# screenshot and screencast tool with annotation

Tags: gnome, screen, gnome-screenshot

I'm currently using the stock screen grabber from gnome

And I'm also using the Zoho annotator to add annotations, like this

[image]

but it only works on web pages

Is there some tool like the stock gnome screen grabber that somes with ubuntu 22.04 (which also allows to record videos) that would also allow me to add annotations?

Answer (score 1):

[Flameshot](https://flameshot.org/) allows for editing the screenshot while you take it.